Changing package name causes error "BuildConfig is defined multiple times"
I've exported my app from Android Studio as a signed bundle, but when I upload it to the Google Play Console I get an error message saying that I've used the wrong package name.
So I go back into my Android Studio project and I have 2 Android Manifests:

The one under 'launcher' has the correct package name, but the one under 'unityLibrary' has this package name: package="com.unity3d.player"
If I change that to the correct package name, I get the following error message:
(I've edited the pathway as it contains my package name)

Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
There was a failure while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Type com.COMANY NAME.APPNAME.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/user/Desktop/Testing Friday/launcher/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/COMPANY NAME/APPNAME/BuildConfig.dex, /Users/user/Desktop/Testing Friday/unityLibrary/build/.transforms/54c963f251167a056d3b2805964fcbef/transformed/release/com/COMPANY NAME/APPNAME/BuildConfig.dex

If I delete one of them and try to generate a signed app bundle, it shows the same error and the folder rebuilds itself.
Is there anywhere else the package name needs to be changed, or am I missing something else?
